# Apollo Typescript Argument Type is not assignable to parameter type MutationFunctionOptions

Tags: typescript, apollo

I'm fairly new to using Typescript, so please be kind, but I want to get this working. I'm using Apollo's useMutation which works fine, but Im getting a Typescript error when passing the variables:

```
"Argument Type {variables: {input: any}} is not assignable to parameter type MutationFunctionOptions"
```

From googling I've tried importing QueryFunctionOptions, MutationFunctionOptions, OperationVariables from @apollo/client and using them in various ways, but I cannot find how I'm supposed to use them.

Any help appreciated!

```
const [mutateFunction, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(SET_ORDER_SHIIPING_ADDRESS);

const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    const response = await mutateFunction({
        variables: {
            input: {
              test: "123"
            }
        }
    });
    console.log(response)
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you set up the graphql in TypeScript with tool like GraphQL Code Generator. You can check the official documentation https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/static-typing/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).